# C++ coordinating processes when launched?

Tags: c++, process, launch

Using C++ I'm planning to have a `producer` process writing a data `vector` and then several `consumer` processes reading that data.  There will be a shared memory segment (Boost::Interprocess) where the data `vector` will be stored.  Issue is: I have no control over the order in which the processes will be launched by a third party application, it could be that the `consumer` might launch before the `producer` has produced any data.  What mechanisms are available to coordinate the processes so that the `consumer` processes can be commanded to wait patiently until the `producer` signals the data is ready; no matter what the order in which the processes launch?

Answer (score 0):

I guess named semaphore is a good choice. Your producer and consumers application should agree (hard-coded) the name of the semaphore, something like /tmp/mySem and only the producer must create and post the semaphore while the consumers should wait for semaphores existance and state.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Are you able to give a quick example of how to set up and use a semaphore as you suggest?

Comment: I see in the Boost documentation that when a post() operation takes place on a semaphore that only one waiting process is awoken.  How may all the waiting threads be awoken, either all together or one-by-one?

Comment: Maybe you should use conditional variable synchronization mchenizm and not semaphore. Conditional variable as mutex can be created as shared and then you can use broadcast() API to wake all waiters at once. In PTHREAD library you need to look for pthread_cond_init(), pthread_condattr_setpshared(), pthread_mutex_init() and pthread_cond_broadcast

Answer (score 0):

If creating shared memory is responsibility of producer process, then you can use boost barrier for synchronizing startup.

You can create a barrier for creating shared memory, maybe some number of jobs to deploy. After reaching this barrier, consumer processes can continue to process them.

You can look to details of boost barrier at this [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/barrier.html)

Comment: Ok I see; So I'd need to provide to the Barrier object at instantiation the number of processes to wait on.  That number would have to be either hard-coded or provided by the user?  See, it would be really good if the program could use a more flexible mechanism where it could handle any number of processes without user interaction.